# run shell script from within app

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0, cakephp-2.1

I have a need to run this

```
./Console/cake AclExtras.AclExtras aco_sync
```

in my app in the controller. Is that possible? how would I do that.
thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for a way to execute an external script in CakePHP - one of the methods specified here should work: http://chipmunkninja.com/Program-Execution-in-PHP%3A-exec-m@